# TSQL For Triggers

Tags: t-sql, triggers

Sorry but I'm struggling with the online documentation.

What exactly is the difference for a **FOR** trigger compared to a AFTER and INSTEAD OF?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FOR` and the `AFTER` trigger is the same. You specify them in the same way and they do the same thing:

```
CREATE TRIGGER sometrigger on sometable FOR INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE

CREATE TRIGGER sometrigger on sometable AFTER INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE
```

The `INSTEAD OF` trigger is something completely different. When you specify a trigger with the instead of then the trigger will execute instead of the insert, update and delete. This can be useful when you have views. So you can control what should be delete, updated and inserted in the views underlying tables

Here is an [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc164047.aspx) to explain the triggers in more depth